# What is the bracket operator in: (0, fs.existsSync)('/usr/bin/chromium-browser')

Tags: javascript

What does the `(0, fs.existsSync)(...)` expression do and what is the definition of this expression?

**Example**

```js
let exists = (0, fs.existsSync)('/usr/bin/chromium-browser');

if (exists) {
  return;
}

// ... other code here

throw new Error('...')
```

I code in JavaScript for 10+ years and just came across this expression in a library, but I have no idea what this is.

I believe to understand the expression converts the `undefined` value returned by `fs.existsSync` to `0` if the file `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` doesn't exist and otherwise returns `true`. However, I can't find any expression or operator definition on mozilla.org or anywhere else.

All operators and expressions on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators don't match any of the signatures of the expression.